# What is __ChadronAlwaysEqualString?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a cloud based Ruby app with a public API. My server log files are showing attempts to access the API with the above odd parameter. Specifically, I have a GET request like :

```
GET "/tenant/api/resource/__ChadronAlwaysEqualString
```

I Googled the string and there are a handful of results for it which suggest that it's somehow an Android thing. For example, someone else saw

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: __ChadronAlwaysEqualString (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM `MyTable` WHERE `myColumn`=__ChadronAlwaysEqualString LIMIT 1
```

Can anyone shed any light on what this might be?

Comment: I see __ChadronAlwaysEqualString in crash logs as string in intent bundle. Only Nexus 4 with Android 6.0.1

Comment: people elsewhere on internet are suggesting it comes from a bot